# Xamarin Studio not launching iOS Project. error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 10.0.2 device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode8, xamarin-studio

My Xamarin development was working fine yesterday and is now showing this error message when trying to run the project:

> error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 10.0.2 (14A456) 
>   device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and
>   then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support
>   files.

I have updated Xcode to 8.1, Xamarin Studio is on the latest stable build and I've upgraded to macOS Sierra, but I still have this issue. Colleagues with the same dev environment as me are still able to run the project fine. I'm also able to open a different iOS project with the same settings and it will deploy to the phone fine.

Other things I've tried:

- Complete uninstall/re-install of Xamarin Studio.
- The Alpha build of Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Have you loaded Xcode and accepted the licence agreement?

Comment: @AlanClark Yes. I have also created a new project and run the app on a phone, as instructed from the Xamarin installation instructions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: @EugenioDeHoyos yes mine is working now. I think what you need to try is making sure you have an iPhone with the latest iOS update, then try and run the project. After that you should be able to run your app using iPhones with lower versions of iOS installed.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHakimi for the response.  I ended up using a different phone in the meantime, but I'll update this thread if I find anything useful once I try it out again.  Cheers!

Comment: I have this problem with an iPhone 5 running iOS 10.3 Beta.  It was working with iOS 10 before.

Comment: @EugenioDeHoyos I just realised another fix would to be to try and run it on the simulator first. It should run, then try to run it on the phone again. This has also worked for me.

Comment: @DanielHakimi Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this worked for me:

1. Change the debug configuration to: Debug | iPhoneSimulator
2. Run the solution
3. Change the debug configuration back to: Debug | iPhone
4. Run the solution

Comment: only using iPhoneSimulator pointed out the underlying error of this error message to me - for me it was that xcode required an update. A message that would not show when setting it to iPhone.